# CEV process is a strict supermartingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

It is well-known that for $\gamma>1$ the CEV process
$$
   dX_t = X_t^\gamma dW_t, \quad X_0 > 0,
$$
is a strict supermartingale. Supermartingality follows since $X_t$ is a non-negative local martingale. Is there a short proof that $X_t$ is not a genuine martingale?

Comment: As always "In George we trust", have a look here : https://almostsuremath.com/2010/08/16/failure-of-the-martingale-property/

Comment: Might not be so short though ...